# How do you handle a Master-Detail window with EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, master-detail

This is a problem that I couldn't find any trivial solutions besides that it is so common. I think the question is abstract enough to apply to both WPF and Winforms

**Do you allow inserting childs if the master is still not saved?**

This forces us to have an in-memory collection of items and to save the master and then the childs when the user hits the *save* button

**What happens when deleting a child from an existing master?**

If the user enter to a window for editing a master entity that have some childs, the deletion of a child should be done immediately or it should have an in-memory collection of `deletes` that its replicated when the user hits the *save* buttons.

This further complicates the problem because the program should manage the case when the user add a new child and then delete it, as this child doesn't exist on the database it shouldn't be added to the *deletes* list

**What happens if a child entity is have its own children that can be edited?**

If a master-detail view allow to edit the detail entities, and the edit window for this entities is another master-detail view, the save button if the inner child alters the database or somehow the save is *delayed* until the master save button is clicked

**Do you insert a dummy empty master to make the logic easier?**

I think is easier to insert an empty master entity when first creating one and that all CRUD operation over the master children affect directly the database on the newly created entity and if the *cancel* button is hitted, just delete the master and all its children. *Does anyone have already done this?*

The problem that I see here is that some tables have required values or foreign keys that can't just be assigned with a default value

This would be solved if the program didn't allow the user to add children entities *until* the user have saved the header data of the master detail window